# Multiple Informatica Powercenter Clients on same machine?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have Informatica Powercenter Server version 9.1.0. The client on my machine is version 9.6.1. Since the client and server versions have to be same, I need to install Informatica Powercenter Client version 9.1.0. Can I install client version 9.1.0 without uninstalling version 9.6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in general. I've had some issues due to using same domains.infa config file by both clients. What made it even more difficult was the fact that the repositories in each version had very same names - the host was the only difference. Check this out in case of issues. Otherwise you should be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. I am using both 9.6 and 10.1 in a same machine.

As long as you are connected to correct server repository you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this should be an issue (am running 8.6.1 and 9.1 on my machine) check you have enough space for both though.